# Generate a list from another list transforming each element on Groovy

Tags: groovy

I've got the following code on a Controller

```
    def db = new Sql(dataSource)
    def rawLines = db.rows("SELECT name FROM LINES")
    def lines = []
    /*(db.rows returns the values as [NAME:value] */
    rawLines.each {
        lines.add(it.name)
    }
    /*Then, use lines */
```

I can't keep away the impression that there is probably some way to do this in a more elegant way, something similar to a list comprehension in Python:

```
lines = [ l.name for l in db.rows("SELECT name FROM LINES") ]
```

Having to declare an empty list and then populate it doesn't seem the **best** way of doing things... 
Is it possible to do something like this, or Groovy doesn't allow it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Can't you just use the spread operator, and do:

```
lines = rawLines*.name
```

(see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_spread_operator)

Comment: Unfortunately, this operator doesn't work in Jenkins Pipeline groovy script

Comment: @smoke_lp How about `lines = rawLines.collect { it.name }`

Comment: @tim_yates I think Jenkins doesn't allow `collect` either.

Answer (score 26):

tim_yates' answer is a clean solution when you want to call a method (or property) on each element of list in order to transform it e.g.:

```
[1,2,3]*.multiply(5)
```

but if you want to call a method from another object or do something more complex you can use `collect`:

```
[1, 2, 3].collect {Math.cos(it * Math.PI)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you are using grails, why aren't you simply using the a model class together with the findAll method?
Using plain raw SQL should be done on exceptional cases.

Comment: Yes, this is one of these cases ;-) The table is a view, so there are some problems defining the table as a domain.